# Simple Triangle Face Messed Up - Attaching to Weird Places?

Tags: faces

I'm not sure how to ask this so it makes it hard to search, but what is going on with this face? It's a simple triangle. I'm trying to add a face to 3 vertices and it goes completely wonky and doesn't fit in the vertices at all. It's doing this throughout the entire model no matter where I put my faces. What's going on? It kind of looks like it's attaching assumed edges to the centers of my edges where there aren't even vertices.

[image]

Comment: That looks nothing like a "*Simple Triangle Face*", I see some hair-like loose edges coming out from each vertex. There also seems to be some sort of *Subdivision Surface* modifier at work there whose output will change the appearance of the mesh, also taking into account any loose geometry you have.

Comment: There are many vertices, but I selected only 3 and pressed "F". As far as I know, this should create a simple face with the 3 vertices. No matter their location in the model, it should work perfectly and simply to create a perfect face. I don't know anything about Subdivision Surface modifiers. I simply drew vertices on a 2D plane and started trying to put faces on them.

Comment: The location on the model *does* matter, especially in relative to other elements when connected to the remaining geometry, like your screenshot illustrates. Even more so if you are using a [Subdivision Surface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html) or any other modifier which changes your shape, which from the screenshot looks like you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had somehow accidentally applied a "Catmull-Clark" modifier to the object. Removing this modifier immediately resolved my issue.

Comment: The name of the modifier is "subsurf" or "subdivision subsurface" modifier. Quite powerful and unavoidable to learn... Read about it here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html